# How to get shard from Anemone Stinkhorn in Capital City Runoff?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

When i talk to **Anemone Stinkhorn** in Capital City Runoff it tells me:

> I'm ready for a new school to move in!

What do i have to do to solve this and get the shard from anemone stinkhorn?

Comment: I don't have the game, but I'd guess he's talking about a school of fish?

Comment: @Shinrai It worked. All i had to do is place one fish next to anemone and few more spawned and it was solved. Post this as your answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Glad it was that easy :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "school" in question is a school of fish (best friends of anemones!).  Try giving him some fishy friends.

Answer (score 0):

seperately write fish, then drag it close. it is an anemone, so it needs some fishes

Comment: Please don't spoil the clue that was given. And 'fish' was already stated.